Не работает endpoint кнопки, загружаемой JS
Есть разметка, загружаемая js'ом на страницу:
function updateInfoBlockById(response) {
            $('.pack').empty();
            Object.keys(response).forEach(function(id) {
                var info = response[id];
                document.getElementById('dateBadge').textContent = 'Ближайшее доступное время: ' + info.date;
                let block = `
                    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
                        <li><strong>№: </strong> <span id="number">${info.user_pack_num}</span></li>
                        <li><strong>Сортимент: </strong> <span id="wood_type">${info.wood_type}</span></li>
                        <li><strong>ДхШхВ: </strong> <span id="dimensions">${info.dimensions}</span></li>
                        <li><strong>Объем: </strong> <span id="volume">${info.volume}</span></li>
                    </ul>

                    <button  style="z-index: 1000; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" class="btn btn-sm"
                            hx-get="/stock_plan/edit-pack/${info.data_pack_id}/${info.pack_id}/" hx-target="#dialog">
                       butt
                    </button>
                    <span class="packDate" style="margin: 3px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; font-size: 12px;">${info.date.split(' ')[0]}</span>
                `;
                $('#'+ id ).html(block);



            });

По своей сути каждая итерация предоставляет блок информации со своими данными. И проблема заключается в том, что кнопка при клике на нее не срабатывает. back-end написан на джанго и end-point выглядит следующим образом:
def edit_pack_view(request, data_pack_id, pack_id):
    data_pack_instance = get_object_or_404(DataPack, pk=data_pack_id)
    pack_instance = get_object_or_404(Pack, pk=pack_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditPackForm(request.POST, data_pack_instance=data_pack_instance, pack_instance=pack_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(data_pack_instance=data_pack_instance, pack_instance=pack_instance)
            return HttpResponse(
                status=204,
                headers={
                    'HX-Trigger': json.dumps({
                        "planChanged": None
                    })
                }
            )

    else:
        form = EditPackForm(data_pack_instance=data_pack_instance, pack_instance=pack_instance)
    return render(request, 'stock_plan/edit_pack_form.html', {
        'form': form,
        'data_pack': data_pack_instance,
        'pack': pack_instance
    })

Сам end-point рабочий и вся логика с модальным окном тоже. Так как если поместить эту кнопку статично в файл со статичным url(заранее заданным), то все работает прекрасно.Иногда эта кнопка при перезагрузке может сработать, а чаще всего нет. Ошибок никаких нигде нет.

Кнопка у вас рисуется, однако обработчика клика на нее нет, поэтому ничего не происходит

Не правда, все работает. hx-get срабатывает при клике. Если я переношу эту кнопку в начало файла, например вот так:  <button  style="z-index: 1000; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;" class="btn btn-sm"                             hx-get="/stock_plan/edit-pack/1/1/" hx-target="#dialog">                        butt                     </button> то все прекрасно работает

Если все работает, тогда вопрос то в чем?

В том, что мне нужно динамическая загрузка данных, как в примере. Где html грузится через js, а не вручную. Почему-то именно в такой реализации кнопка не работает.

Потому что кнопка у вас рисуется, а обработчика клика на ней нет(если нет глобального обработчика клика по всему window).

Вот этот вопрос похож на дубликат вашего

То есть после загрузки новых элементов, удаляются обработчики?

Не удаляются. На новых их просто нет и надо их навешивать. Если элемент удаляется, то и его обработчики удаляются

Можете пример привести, как на эту кнопку навесить обработчик?

По ссылке выше есть пример создания обработчиков. В вашем коде нет вообще создания обработчика, поэтому сказать что то определенное сложно.

Благодарю, добавил обработчики. Пофиксилось.
